# C++: emplace to std::unordered_map value containing std::mutex

Tags: c++, mutex, unordered-map, emplace

Could you, please, help me to figure out the right syntax of how to `emplace` into an `std::unordered_map` a value containing an `std::mutex`?

Here is an example:

```cpp
#include <mutex>
#include <unordered_map>

using SubMap = std::unordered_map<int, float>;
struct MutexedSubMap{ std::mutex mutex; SubMap subMap; };
std::unordered_map<int, MutexedSubMap> m;

// The following do not work:
// m.emplace(7, MutexedSubMap{});
// m.emplace(7);
// m.emplace(7, {});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`emplace` forwards the arguments to a constructor. You can write a constructor for `MutexedSubMap`:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <unordered_map>

using SubMap = std::unordered_map<int, float>;
struct MutexedSubMap{ SubMap subMap; std::mutex mutex; MutexedSubMap(const SubMap& sm): subMap(sm){} };
std::unordered_map<int, MutexedSubMap> m;

int main() {
    m.emplace(7, SubMap{});
}
```

Note that `m[7];` would have the same effect.